# react-konva: Property does not exist on type 'never'

Tags: reactjs

**I'm trying to use toDataURL with React-Canvas.**

I found this example on their website. It's exactly what I want to do!

[image: Edit react-konva-export-demo]

**I copied/pasted the code, but I keep having an error:**

> Property 'toDataURL' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)

```
const handleExport = () => {
  if (stageRef.current != null) {
    console.log(stageRef.current);
    const uri = stageRef.current.toDataURL();
    console.log(uri);
  }
};
```

Any idea how to figure it out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **If you are using typescripts, add a type to `useRef` and correct your `equals operator`**

So it should be something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import Konva from 'konva';   //<-- Import Konva namespace

export const App = () => {

  const stageRef = React.useRef<Konva.Stage>(null);  // <-- Add type to generic `useRef`

  const handleExport = () => {
    if (stageRef.current !== null) {  // <-- Correct equals operator
      console.log(stageRef.current);
      const uri = stageRef.current.toDataURL();
      console.log(uri);
    }
  };

  return (
    ...
  );
};
```

**Working example in Typescripts**

[image: Edit cocky-rhodes-2doei]

Comment: Thanks ! It works perfectly. I have to learn a little bit more about the typing. I lose so much time on these small bugs.

Comment: Yeah, typescript's learning curve is tough at the start. It's best to have someone to learn from.